# How to set ImageView height dynamically with Picasso?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, height, picasso

I'm using **Picasso** to display 2 `ImageView` side by side inside a `GridView` of 2 columns.
The thing is that I can't find a way to set my `ImageView` height dynamically, without stretching the image.

Here is the code :

**ImageListAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // ViewHolder pattern in play
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (null == convertView) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_image, parent, false);
        viewHolder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_button);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(imageResources[position])
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(viewHolder.mImageView);

    return convertView;
}
```

**activity_picasso.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/heenok_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**listview_item_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/iv_button"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="121dp"
  android:background="@null"
  android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />
```

I have tried without `.fit.centerInside()` in my `Adapter` and adding `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in my `ImageView`. It works but due to a large number of image, I experience **huge** lags, my images are disordered and the app just crash.

If I change my `android:layout_height=""` to `wrap_content` without deleting `.fit.centerInside()`, the screen is just blank as if there was no images...

If anyone got an answer, I'd be glad !

Comment: First of all, if you specify android:scaleType="fitXY" on your ImageView your image will be distorted if the ImageView doesn't have the same ratio as your image. Choose a different scaleType depending on what effect you want to achieve. .fit.centerInside() is useless if you use another scaleType so just remove it. Also be sure to use a RecyclerView to use less... WAY MORE LESS... memory otherwise you will face a memory crash with too many images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  .../>
```

But you seem to have performance issues:
Use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) instead (as DustyMan already mentioned) with a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)